# Is "cancel posting of my letter" or " cancel sending of my letter" correct?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, gerunds

I am writing an email to cancel the posting of my application. But I am quite confused as to whether it is

> a. I wish to cancel posting of my application to the company mentioned on my form

or

> b. I wish to cancel sending of my application to the company mentioned on my form

Which one is right?

Answer (score 6):

I would say:

"I wish to withdraw my application to the company mentioned on my form".

If I was being more formal I'd name the company instead of alluding to it:

"I wish to withdraw my application to Xerox."

You might also add:
"Please refer to details in my form."

"Withdraw" is not used in all cases, it indicates pulling back something you have presented forward, often formal documents, verbal offers.  "I'm withdrawing my offer to buy your house."  "Withdraw" can also be more literal as in moving yourself out of a situation.  To be a "withdrawn" person is to be shy and rarely reach out to others.

Similar words:
In a technical field you might "roll back" a computer transaction to a previous state, or in finance you would "cancel" a payment.

Answer (score 3):

At one time *to post* was fairly common as a synonym for *to mail*. With the rise of the internet, however, where *post* usually means 'to publish, to exhibit to general view', this use has become ambiguous. I would avoid it.

This is not to say, however, that *send* is your best choice. It appears that you are communicating with an employment service of some sort which holds your information and sends it by some medium to prospective employers. In that case *send* is perfectly OK, or *forward*. But [GoogleNgrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=post+an+application%2Cmail+an+application%2Csend+an+application%2Csubmit+an+application&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that by far the most usual verb with *application* is *submit*:

[image]

A final note: whatever verb you end up using, the *of my* phrase is superfluous and stiff. *I wish to cancel sending my application* is quite sufficient. *Of my* is needed only if you employ a 'mere' noun, which cannot take an object as a gerund can: *I wish to cancel submission of my application*.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what do you mean with _frank noun_?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno Sorry - old LitCrit usage. I mean a noun which although derived from the verb cannot act in a verbal capacity. The  gerund *submitting* may take an object, like the verb from which it is derived; the noun *submission* cannot.